# Looping over 1st dimension of 3D numpy array to create a smaller 3D array, via slicing

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, 3d, netcdf

this is my first post so apologies if the formatting isn't quite right. I am writing some code for my masters dissertation, in which I am am studying satellite images of sea ice near the Alaskan coast. The satellite instrument I am using has 9 cameras, so for each image/band I have 9 subdatasets, which I am trying to loop over: NIR_data is a 3D numpy array, with the following dimensions: 9,512,256. I am trying to create a new 3D array, which is a 10x10 subset of the original array, defined by the pixel coordinates [256:266,112:122]. So if I was just doing it for 1 file the code would be:

```
NIR_BRF = NIR_data[i][256:266,112:122]
```

So, trying to loop over the first dimension of my NIR_data array, this is the closest I am getting:

```
for i,f in enumerate(NIR_data):
    NIR_BRF[i] = NIR_data[i][256:266,112:122]
```

where NIR_BRF is a predefined, empty array measuring 9,10,10. The result is a 9,10,10 array, however all the values in this array are identical, i.e. the loop hasn't worked.
I hope I've explained this well enough, I know this shouldn't be too difficult, but I'm struggling to get my brain working properly.

Many thanks

Alex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here no need to iterate through  3D array . 
Remember when you want to perform some operations on elements of array (may be after getting the shorter array) then you will need to iterate over it.. when you want to create another subarray from existing there will be a way always to get rid of iteration in most the cases..here you just have to create subarray (Here python behaves as if its functional programming lang) 
here the possible fix is to use the syntax

```
 [dim1_start:dim1_stop:dim1_step,dim2_start:dim2_stop:dim2_step,...dimn_start:dimn_stop:dimn_step]
```

> when you don't give start:stop it assumes everything , and when you dont give step it assumes step as 1 unit

so use 
`NIR_BRF = NIR_data[:, 256:266, 112:122]`

Comment: Great, that did it for me, just to be clear this is how it works:

`NIR_BRF = NIR_data[:,256:266,112:122]`

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
NIR_BRF = NIR_data[:, 256:266, 112:122]
```

There’s then no need to preallocate the array.